Show that $AH:BH=DH:CH$ in a parallelogram $ABCD$.
$ABCD$ is a parallelogram with center $O$.
$E$ is the point on $AB$ such that $∡ADE=∡ECB$.
$F$ is the reflection point of $E$ wrt $O$.
$G$ is the point on $AD$ such that $∡ABG=∡GCD$.
$H$ is a point such that $∡HEG=∡GFH$.
Show that

$AH:BH=DH:CH$.
The angle bisector of $\angle EGF$ is parallel to an axis of the rectangular hyperbola through $A,B,C,D$.
(From this page there is a unique rectangular hyperbola through four non-orthocentric points.)



Some progress:
Page 100 in the book Geometry of Conics proved the following fact:


The points $E,F,G$ are given, the locus of $H$ such that $∡HEG=∡GFH$ is a rectangular hyperbola through $E,F,G$ with center $O$ the midpoint of $EF$.

Theorem 7.4 in this blogpost is about the locus of $X$ such that $X A_1 \cdot X A_2=X B_1 \cdot X B_2$ for four points $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$. But the blogpost is more general than this problem which is a special case when the four points form a parallelogram.
